# django and mypy with apps in a subfolder

Tags: python, django, mypy

We have a Django project with the following setup:

We have our apps in an `apps` folder. We added all those apps to the python path at `settings.py` level.

We then can refer and import these apps like so:

```py
from apps.booking.models import Booking
# or
from booking.models import Booking
```

Now, we want to use mypy for type checking purposes.

The issue is that mypy does not recognize the import `from booking.models import Booking` and complains about missing stubs for this module. This make the typing very unreliable and not very useful as `Booking` is then typed as `Any`. It works fine with an import as follow however `from apps.booking.models import Booking`

**Is there a way to make mypy understand the path without the prefix `apps.` ?**

I tried to use `mypy_path = $MYPY_CONFIG_FILE_DIR/apps` in `mypy.ini` but without any success...

Edit:

For clarity, here is my full mypy.ini:

```ini
[mypy]
mypy_path = $MYPY_CONFIG_FILE_DIR/apps
show_error_codes = true
sqlite_cache = true
plugins =
    mypy_django_plugin.main

[mypy.plugins.django-stubs]
django_settings_module = "myapp.settings"
```

Comment: Why did setting `mypy_path` fail? How did you set it exactly?

Comment: I just edited my question and added my full mypy.ini file. `mypy` don't compute the file I try to type check and fail before in another file, with the following error: `Found 10 errors in 2 files (errors prevented further checking)`

The most probable culprit for stopping the analysis is this error: `error: Source file found twice under different module names: "utils.chronos" and "apps.utils.chronos"`.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it's because of `__init__.py` file.
Did you add `__init__.py` file in your apps folder?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, see how do I write a good answer [answer].

Comment: Yes, there is a `__init__.py` in the `apps/` folder. Just to be sure, I removed that `__init__.py` file but without any success